# Apache reverse proxy forwarding https header

Tags: apache, header, proxy, reverse

I have successfully installed reverse proxy on Apache. It works like a charm. I'm using it to proxy https request to http. My problem is that I need to forward variable SERVER_HTTPS to my end server, to indicate if person is using ssl connection or just http. I have found one way to do:
 Each time I can forward HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO variable and check on end server:

```
   if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

But this variant is not good for me, because I can't edit the end servers scripts. Lets say that I don't even have access to it. But I know how to check if it is forwarded. So, Generally my question is: Is there any way that I can forward this variable? I have seen one more variant, with Rewrite engine , but it didn't work for me and there is no detailed information. Maybe If I will set my server on Nginx + apache this will send this header variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit the end server configuration, take a look at mod_rpaf RPAF_SetHTTPS option :

https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf

Comment: have installed original mod_rpaf, it returns correct ip, but it only forwards X_FORWARDED_FOR. When I'm adding RPAF_SetHTTPS On or RPAFSetHTTPS On in its config, it gives me the error:Invalid command 'RPAF_setHTTPS', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
After that I have installed the package that you suggested to me, it doesn't do anything. Currently trying to fix that

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It works fine, I just had to made my own build for Debian.